# How to show error in a specific input in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, validation, input

I have this `state` that represents products.

```
const [rowsData, setRowsData] = useState([
    { width: "", height: "", quantity: "" },
  ]);
```

And this `table` which the user can add how many rows(product) as necessary or delete.

```
return (
    <> 
      {rowsData.map((data, index) => {
        const { width, height, quantity} = data;
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{index + 1}</td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="number"
                value={width}
                onChange={(evnt) => handleChange(index, evnt)}
                name="width"
                className={wError ? "input input-error border-2 input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" : "input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"}            
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="number"
                value={height}
                onChange={(evnt) => handleChange(index, evnt)}
                name="height"
                className={hError ? "input input-error border-2 input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" : "input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"}
              />{" "}
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="number"
                value={quantity}
                onChange={(evnt) => handleChange(index, evnt)}
                name="quantity"
                className={qError ? "input input-error border-2 input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" : "input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"}
              />{" "}
            </td>
            <td>
              {index !==0 ? <button className="btn" onClick={() => deleteTableRows(index)}>
                x
              </button>: null}
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
```

The `handlChange()` fucntion to detect any change in the `input` fields and runs a `setState`.

```
const handleChange = (index, evnt) => {
    const { name, value } = evnt.target;
    const rowsInput = [...rowsData];
    rowsInput[index][name] = value;
    setRowsData(rowsInput);
  };
```

All the fields must accept **numbers only** on submit button, if the user input anything else a red error border should appear around the input field which holds the error.

My solution to the issue was this:

1- A made 3 error `usestats` for each field (w->width, h->height, q-> quantity)

```
  const [wError, setWError] = useState(false);
  const [hError, setHError] = useState(false);
  const [qError, setQError] = useState(false);
```

2- I checked the `value` of each input fields if it's a number or not.

```
const createOrder = () => {
    let wCheck, hCheck, qCheck

    rowsData.map((e) => {
       wCheck = !isNaN(e.width) && !isNaN(parseFloat(e.width));
       hCheck = !isNaN(e.height) && !isNaN(parseFloat(e.height));
       qCheck = !isNaN(e.quantity) && !isNaN(parseFloat(e.quantity));

    });
  };
```

3- Set the error variables(wError, hError, qError) to be the opposite of the check variables(wCheck, hCheck, qCheck)

```
      setWError(!wCheck);
      setHError(!hCheck);
      setQError(!qCheck);
```

4- I Style the input field based on the error variable (as shown in the first snippet).

```
className={qError ? "input input-error border-2 input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" : "input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"}
```

**Solution Conclusion**

This solution is terrible. It has multiple bugs that i couldn't fix [image: Bugs]

As you can see the error is based on the last input field only. So the error checker marks the entire column as error **(3rd column)** and sometimes it marks all the column valid **(1st column)**

How do i modify the function to target a specific input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new property to your product array that will store the error message, or even a boolean that will be `true` when the input has some validation error. In your `handleChange()` function, you can validate if the value is invalid and set that field. In the loop, you check the field and if there is an error, set the border to red to the input of current iteration.

Remember to update the array using the spread operator to ensure the re-render is triggered.

An example below:

```js
export function App(props) {

  const [rows, setRows] = useState([
    {value: '', error: false},
    {value: '', error: false},
    {value: '', error: false},
  ])

  function handleChange(evt, index) {
    let value = evt.target.value
    rows[index].value = value
    rows[index].error = !isNaN(value) && !isNaN(parseFloat(value))
    setRows([...rows])
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {rows.map((row, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <input 
                style={{'border': row.error ? '1px solid red' : ''}} 
                value={row.value} 
                onChange={(evt) => handleChange(evt, index)} 
                placeholder="Enter value"
               />
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To validate if some input has an error to disable the submit operation, you can check if some `error` field is `true`. If there isn't any with `true`, the form is valid.

[React Playground Example](https://playcode.io/1369232)